# Get a motor to move my camera based on a point in an image

Tags: dc-motor, programming, math, camera

Let's say that I have this image:

[image]

Obviously, the camera is pointing to the center of the image, but I need it to point to the center of the bbox. I need to calculate how to get my motor to move so that the camera will move from point A (the center of the image) to point B (the center of the bbox).

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi Pico and a regular DC motor (I can't move the motor by degrees, only by giving it a '1').

Any ideas?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not an electronics design question.

Comment: If the target object is stationary, a PID controller would be a good option.  There are lots of websites and engineering textbooks that describe PID controllers and variants thereof (i.e., PI or PD controllers).  (A PID controller is a type of closed-loop feedback control system.) If the target object is moving, a PID controller might still work, but if not, you'll need to use a more sophisticated algorithm, e.g., a Kalman filter.  Michel van Biezen has some excellent lectures on Kalman filters on his YouTube channel:  https://youtu.be/CaCcOwJPytQ

Answer (score 1):

I would say the hardest part is probably to generate the image you have shown.
As soon as you have found a way to calculate the point to track, the rest would be very straight forward.

Calculate whether the point is to the left or to the right of center, and drive motor in the required direction. As soon as the point is in the center, stop the motor. Simple as that.

Depending on how fast the calculations can be done, how heavy the mechanics are etc, you might need to throw a PID regulator or something similar to it to get decent performance. Otherwise, you'll probably end up oscillating around the center.

This of course assumes that you can calculate and update the position in real time.